# How to find the area where $\frac{1}{z^2-4}$, $z \in \mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-integration

Suppose that you are given a problem of finding the following complex integral:

$$\int_\tau \frac{1}{z^2-4} dz$$

where $\tau = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z|=4 \}$. My question is (in the context of this problem): how can we find the area, in which this function - $\frac{1}{z^2-4}$ - is holomorphic?

P.S. I am not interested in finding the integral using Residue Theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since:
$$\frac{1}{z^2-4}=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{z-2}-\frac{1}{z+2}\right)$$
$f(x)$ is a meromorphic function with simple poles in $z=\pm 2$, hence it is a holomorphic function over any region that does not enclose such singularities.

Even if you are not interested, your integral is zero since the residues in the singularities inside $\gamma$ are opposite.

Comment: In the solution given to this problem, it is said that 1/(z^2-4) is holomorphic at all points {z: |z|<=4} \ {{z: |z+2|<=1} Union {z: |z-2|<=1} }

Comment: That is for sure a region that does not enclose the singularities.

Comment: But why this specific region? Is it arbitrary?

Comment: Yes, it is arbitrary. Probably your book (or professor) just want to show how to reduce the problem to two disjoint circles enclosing the singularities. It works also if you set the radius of the smaller circles equal to $\frac{1}{100}$, just to say.